# Can't get routeparams individually

Tags: angularjs, routes

retrieving the return is successful but can't seem to get the attributes individually

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid', 'ngRoute', "ngAnimate", "ngAria", 'ngMaterial']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider)
{
    $routeProvider.
    when('/:energyId/:energyChain/:resourceId/:facilityId',
    {
        templateUrl: '/Content/resourceTemplate.html',
        controller: 'detailsController',
        resolve: {
            SomeData: function ($route) {
                return $route.current.params;
            }
        }

    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/param1/param1/param1/param1'
    });
}]);

myApp.controller('detailsController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function ($scope,SomeData, $routeParams) {

    //this doesnt work 
    $scope.statusLabel = SomeData.energyChain;
    //but this works   $scope.statusLabel = SomeData;
```

Comment: take a look at `$routeParams` object by logging it to console in controller

Answer (score 2):

```
 myApp.controller('detailsController', ['$scope','SomeData','$routeParams', function ($scope,SomeData, $routeParams)
```

wrong sequence of dependency

Comment: tried, sorry but it is not working the problem is accessing it .I get l {"energyId":"param1","energyChain":"param1","resourceId":"param1","facilityId":"param1"} result while logging Some data but when I try to access SomeData.energyID it doesnt work. Whats wron with it